# Android provide from hilt

Tags: android, dagger, dagger-hilt

How I can make transfer parameter from fragment to dagger module used hilt?

I would like that

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class TestModule {
   @Singleton
   @Provides
   fun provideAccountApi(type: Type): AccountApi = when (type) {
      Type.Type_1 -> retrofitProvider.newInstance<AccountType1Api>().create()
      else -> retrofitProvider.newInstance<AccountType2Api>().create()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this kind of requirement by using @Binds method along with Qualifier annotations.

Here I have tried to mention scenario which may be helpful in your case.(I am not sure about your project idea but as per your code snip-it and my thought, I am going to mention that scenario here...)

1. Define a custom qualifier annotation like as bellow:

   ```
    @Qualifier
    @Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
    annotation class TypeQualifier(val value: Type)
   ```
2. Here is the modified module.(you can also modify it as per your requirement.)

   ```
    @Module
    @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
    object TestModule {
        @Singleton
        @Provides
        fun provideRetrofit(): Retrofit {
            // Provide your Retrofit instance here.
        }

        @TypeQualifier(Type.Type_1)
        @Provides
        fun provideAccountType1Api(retrofit: Retrofit): AccountApi {
            return retrofit.create(AccountType1Api::class.java)
        }

        @TypeQualifier(Type.Type_2)
        @Provides
        fun provideAccountType2Api(retrofit: Retrofit): AccountApi {
            return retrofit.create(AccountType2Api::class.java)
        }

        @Binds
        abstract fun bindType(type: Type): Type

        @Singleton
        @Provides
        fun provideAccountApi(@TypeQualifier type: Type, @TypeQualifier(Type.Type_1) type1Api: AccountApi, @TypeQualifier(Type.Type_2) type2Api: AccountApi): AccountApi {
            return when (type) {
                Type.Type_1 -> type1Api
                Type.Type_2 -> type2Api
            }
        }
    }
   ```

Now, you can inject the dynamic Type into your activity or fragment and Hilt will provide the appropriate AccountApi instance based on the selected Type.

```
    @AndroidEntryPoint
    class YourActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        @Inject
        lateinit var type: Type
    
        @Inject
        lateinit var accountApi: AccountApi
    
        // ...
    
        fun someMethod() {
            // You can use 'type' and 'accountApi' here.
        }
    }
```

Note: This snip-it is for your reference, you have to modify it as per your requirement as well as as per architecture(clean architecture, MVVM etc.) which you have used in your project.

Also, If you are not aware bout the Qualifier annotations, kindly refer the [official documentation.](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android)